# Como obter informações de um servidor TCP e enviar para o cliente em java

Tags: java, socket

A ideia é o seguinte:tenho um servidor TCP que calcula a quantidade de água de uma caixa de água,quando esta com 250 litros deve avisar o cliente que precisa encher de novo.
Mas quem possui a informação que a água esta acabando é o servidor.
Como posso passar a informação para que cliente fique sabendo que é necessário encher de água?

Meu método executa.

```
public void executa() throws IOException  {

        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(this.porta);

        System.out.println("Porta 12345 aberta!");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {//imprime sequência de 10 números inteiros aleatórios
            quant=quant - gerador.nextInt(400);//quant=15000
            System.out.println("aqui mostra a quantidade : "+quant);
            if(quant<=250){
                System.out.println("quantidade de agua a baixo,encha de agua ");
                i=10;
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            // aceita um cliente
            Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println("Nova conexão com o cliente "+ cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            // adiciona saida do cliente a lista
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            this.clientes.add(ps);

            // cria tratador de cliente numa nova thread
            TrataCliente tc = new TrataCliente(cliente.getInputStream(), this);
            new Thread(tc).start();

        }
}
```

Comment: Qual erro ocorre?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `ConcurretHashMap` para armazenar a lista de clientes conectados

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Socket> clientesAtivos = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Socket>();

clientesAtivos.put(clientsocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), clientsocket);
```

Quando a caixa estiver com 250 litros, percorra a lista dos clientes e envie a mensagem avisando.

```
for(String clientHost : clientesAtivos.keySet()) {
      // obtenha cada socket e envie a mensagem
}
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625500/how-to-broadcast-messages-to-all-clients-using-tcp-in-java)